# How to fail with error message "Too many open files in python"

Tags: python, file

I created 10000 files - my default limit was " ulimit -n 1024" - I expected following script to fail with a message like "Too many files open" , but it didn't fail.  (/tmp/files has 10000 files)

Any thoughts on where am i going wrong?

```
import os
listfiles=os.listdir('/tmp/files')
count=0
f=''
for file in listfiles:
        fn=f+str(count)
        fn=open(file,'w')
        fn.write('hello')
        print 'file=',file
        count=count+1

print count
```

Comment: thanks guys add it to a list makes this to work :P I get the expected error message.

Comment: yeah..did that now..waited for answers on the comment sections..all of them are right ..

Comment: I tried to answer at one of them. If something isn't clear, feel free to open a new question explaining what you didn't understood :)

Comment: okay thanks - I now i got it :) I thought , I was assigning file to f0,f1,f2 etc ..but I was wrong. It always assigns to fn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for file in listfiles:
        fn = f+str(count)    # what is this supposed to do?
        fn = open(file,'w')  # old file handle gets garbage collected and closed
        fn.write('hello')
        print 'file=',file
        count = count + 1
```

Every time you rebind `fn` the previous file gets closed. It's possible that in jython for example the file doesn't get closed immediately, but it very likely will still be garbarge collected and closed before you exceed the 1024 file limit

Try storing the file objects in a list like this:

```
import os
listfiles = os.listdir('/tmp/files')
count = 0
f = ''
fn = []
for file in listfiles:
        fn.append(open(file,'w'))
        fn[-1].write('hello')
        print 'file=',file
        count = count + 1

print count
```

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand 'i did fn=f+str(count)' before open with new file' even now it reuses old fn ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think setting ``fn`` to this seemingly arbitrary value will help you here. You need to keep references to the open file in memory (make a set or list, for example).

Comment: I assume fn similar to file descriptor in C language.In such case if have lot of file descriptors like fp1 = open('file','w') and fp2 = open ('file','w')..At some point ,I expected it to fail,with out adding it to list..But anyway adding to list works .. may be python & C uses file handles differently.thanks for the help :)

Comment: @lakshmipathi, C doesn't have garbage collection, so if you set `fp1` to a different file, the old one hangs around wasting memory and the descriptor which you can no longer access

Answer (score 2):

Rebinding `fn` causes the reference count of the old object to drop to 0, causing it to be reaped. Append the files to a list instead.

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand 'i did fn=f+str(count)' before open with new file' even now it reuses old fn ?

Comment: @lakshmipathi: `fn` is a variable holding your file object. A file object is not a string, if you reassign to the variable `fn` a string you'll loose the file object.

Answer (score 2):

You loop brings each file object out of scope, so they are quickly closed, and you don't have more than 1 alive at any time (technically you might have because of GC delay). Just append each file object to a global list and you'll be good crashing your script! :)